# AJAX and Jquery prevent page load on click of button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a gridview where in i load all of the transaction a merchant have (it either e pending transaction, Approved transaction or Rejected Transaction)..My gridview is using template and i have two buttons in it..what i want to happen is to prevent the page from loading when i click either Approve or Reject...And as well as for my Filter.I am using 3 checkboxes (Pending, Approved, Rejected) I used code behind to make my filter.

How can I prevent Page Load when ever i click the button or check the checkboxes in jquery and AJAX.?I have no codes yet, for i have no idea how to use AJAX and i'm not that good in jquery.can you please give me a example.
thank you.

Arianne

Answer (score 0):

using jquery ajax can solve your problem. you send request onclicking of your checkboxes by jquery ajax. if the checkbox is checked then send request and perform your your operation. if operation is complete then send response to your grid.

For jquery-ajax , take help from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Call your JavaScript function from button click event. In Asp.net you can have OnClientClick attribute of button and you can call function in that. You must have return false either in your function or after the function call to prevent postback on button click.

Check sample code below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return ShowAlert();" />

<script  type="text/javascript">
  function ShowAlert()
  {
     alert('hello');
     return false;
  }
</script>
```